# Which is better: Function overriding or passing a function pointer for event handling

Tags: c++, message-queue, listener

So, I'm writing code for a class that will go into a library that will be used by others. This class will intercept and process incoming messages (details are not important but it's using the activemq-cpp library). The outline of this consumer class is

```
class MessageConsumer {
    ...
    public:
        void runConsumer();
        virtual void onMessage(const Message* message);
}
```

where `runConsumer()` sets up the connection and starts listening and `onMessage()` is called when a message is received.

My questions is this: People who'll use this code will each have their own way of processing the different messages. How can I keep `MessageConsumer` generic but offer this flexibility, while keeping their code simple?

Two options:

- Should they inherit a new class from `MessageConsumer` and write their own `onMessage()`?
- Should they pass a pointer to a message handling function to `MessageConsumer`?

What do you think, which option is better and why?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is "it depends," but if you do take the function pointer approach, consider using a `std::function` (or `boost::function`); that way consumers can pass bound member functions.

Comment: James, is there a big difference in complexity between the two, i.e. I haven't done much advanced function pointer coding?

Comment: Nope; `std::function` is not more complex; it just (a) makes your syntax much cleaner and (b) gives consumers of your class more options.  It has a slight performance cost over using an ordinary function pointer, but its performance is on par with calling a virtual function, so it won't be noticeable in 99.999% of the places you want to use it.

Comment: @James: I would advise against this for library code, as using `std::function` et al would then require that clients use the same compiler that OP used to create the library.

Comment: @John:  Are there systems on which you can easily mix and match libraries containing C++ code that are compiled with different compilers?  (I'm slightly embarrassed to say that I don't really know, since almost all of my work has been with Visual C++ where it is painful at best to get libraries built with different versions of the compiler to play nicely together.)

Comment: @James:  I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "systems."  But I can tell you from my own experience that if you even try to write a library function that returns a `std::string` in MSVC10 and try to use that library in an app written MSVC6, you'll have all kinds of problems.  The reason stems from `std::string` being blown out inline.  MSVC thinks it looks like one thing, while MSVC10 thinks it looks like something else.

Comment: @John: it's typical, that's why the best way to deliver the library is to deliver the source code and a way to build it :)

Comment: @Matthieu:  Best from the programmer's perspective maybe.  Not the end-user's.  I can only imagine the phone calls I'd get from my mother if MS Office came in source code form that she had to compile.

Comment: @John Dibling: right, I was thinking programmer's here. But Windows features an installer, which is very close to a compiler in that you first download the installer which then get / parameterize what's required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In one approach, clients are allowed to register a callback and then the MessageConsumer invokes the registered callback. This is something like an observer/broadcast design pattern.

The second approach, where clients have to inherit and override MessageConsumer would be something like Strategy design pattern.

Basic design goals suggest to use the weakest relationship to promote loose coupling. Since inhertiance is a stronger relationship as compared to a simple association, everything else being the same Approach 1 is preferred.

From [Herb's article](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/060.htm)

> "Inheritance is often overused, even
>   by experienced developers. Always
>   minimize coupling: If a class
>   relationship can be expressed in more
>   than one way, use the weakest
>   relationship that's practical. Given
>   that inheritance is nearly the
>   strongest relationship you can express
>   in C++ (second only to friendship),
>   it's only really appropriate when
>   there is no equivalent weaker
>   alternative."

But as James points out, it is tough to comment unless the overall design constraints are known clearly.

Comment: Inheritance is weaker relationship as its allows to carry a functoin and its context together, making callback argument context-independent.

Comment: @Basilevs:  A bound pointer to member function also combines function with context and does so without coupling.

Comment: @Basilevs: Inheritance is the strongest relationship after Friendship. Consider all the consequences of modifying the base class.

Comment: @James: member function? How do you pass that as an argument?

Comment: @Matthieu: they are the same for modifying type of callback. Inheritance is strong, but only between Message and MessageImpl. But we are talking about MessageConsumer -> MessageImpl relationship.

Comment: @Basilevs:  Using `std::bind` to bind the pointer to member function to an instance, then storing that bound member function in a `std::function`.

Comment: @Basilevs: not really, the `MessageConsumer` depends on `Message` interface, changing the interface forces a recompilation. Though I do agree that in this precise case, if `Message` is simply used for a single function, then both solutions have exactly identical dependencies issues, it's just that inheritance will require more typing...

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance will make your library more OO-friendly and may improve readability. But really, the choices are about the same since the compiler will check that the user has supplied the function (assuming you declare a pure virtual handler in the base class), and the underlying mechanism will be accomplished via a pointer anyway (virtual table in the case of inheritance).

Answer (score 1):

Pure virtual functions allow the compiler to check that the client code implements the handler.  Virtual dispatch is active immediately after an object is constructed, and someone looking at the derived class can reason accurately about its handling.  Data needed for the handling can be conveniently and clearly grouped into the derived class.  Factories can still select a particular derived class to instantiate.

Function pointers are run-time state, so there's a little more care needed to initialise them in a timely fashion, for optional run-time checks on their being set and error handling, and to reason about which set is in effect during program execution.  With that comes more freedom to vary them within the lifetime of the object.

A third alternative is a template policy class, or the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern, to lock in the behaviours at compile time.  This potentially allows inlining of callbacks, dead-code elimination and other optimisations.

Comment: First time I've heard about the CRTP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), it's awesome!

Answer (score 0):

virtual function or tepmlated functor are the way to go. These approaches give greater flexibility ad looser coupling than function pointer one.

To illustrate that - function pointer approach can be wrapped with first two, but not vice-versa.

```
void cbFunction();

class Interface {
  virtual void act() =0 ;
};

class CbFuctionWrapper:public Interface {
public:
  virtual void act() {cbFunction()};
};

class AnotherImpl: public Interface {
  Context _c; // You can't pass additional context with usual function without downcasting, but OO is all about that.
public:
  virtual void act() {...}
}
```